# Using a regex to remove a specific #tag in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring

I am trying to parse a string in Objective-C to delete an exact match of a specific #tagged word.  I can create a regular expression and delete a specific word without issue, but when I try to remove a string with a leading "#" it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
NSString *originalString = @"This is just a #test that isn't working";
NSString *hashTag = @"#test";
NSString *placeholder = @"\\b%@\\b";
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:placeholder, hashTag];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:originalString
                                options:0
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [originalString length])
                           withTemplate:@""];
```

The issue is that even if the original string includes the string #test, it's not removed.  If I swap "#test" with "test", everything works fine, but that's not what I'm trying to do.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there isn't a word character exists between a space and `#`. Both are non-word characters. So i suggest you to remove the starting `\\b`

```
NSString *placeholder = @"%@\\b";
```

OR

Use a negative lookbehind.

```
NSString *placeholder = @"(?<!\\S)%@\\b";
```

`(?<!\\S)` Negative lookbehind which asserts that there isn't a non-space character exists before the match.

To do an exact string match, i suggest you to use this `@"(?<!\\S)%@(?!\\S)"` regex. `(?!\\S)` Negative lookahead which asserts that the match won't be followed by a non-space character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cW4qQ3/8)

Answer (score 0):

is it even necessary to use a regex, would this function not suffice?

```
[yourstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#test" withString:@""];
```

Comment: This was my previous implementation.  But it failed when the string was something like "I am just #testing"  .  I was left with "I am just ing"